# how to Specifies an author / editor to edit one category only?

Tags: categories, user-roles, author

let me say i have a news website and it have many categories like sports ,politics and art . so i want to specify or select one of my authors "Bob" to be an editor for sports only for example .... how this could be ??

i found a level choice to select for editing over multi user something like :

```
administrators == administrator roles
editors == editor level .....etc
```

...in this link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

But i want like this :

```
Bob == admin of political category posts
Maria == admin of Sports category posts
Dr.Adam == admin of health category posts
```

i want to select one (admin)user by name or password  for every category

Comment: Have you already searched [the site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=restrict+category)? Please show us what you have tried yourself.

Comment: i edit my question hope you understand me

Comment: i need any help even if it a link

Comment: i think my question was clear enough ...... i dont have any idea about ! ... sorry but i don't know how to try ...i see the "restricted category" depending on cable of roles for cable of users but i need the opposite of this.... i need to select one of users to can edit or write in one category and this user can't write in other categories